# How to search using the AND operator for Elasticsearch Magento 2

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2, magento2.1

By Default Magento 1 & 2 search functionality will result the records using OR operator which gives sometimes irrelevant records.

In Magento 1, its possible by changing the logic in [Fulltext.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31889/category-search-logic-and-instead-of-or) . Is there any way that I can change the same for Magento 2 Elasticsearch